# Incorrect connection header with MQTT over Websocket with AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I have an issue with AWS IoT. I was using the same code for month. But suddenly it stopped working. I'm using Mqtt over Websocket with AWS IoT.

This is the simple bit of code I use.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.AWSIotException;
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.AWSIotMqttClient;

public class ThingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String clientEndpoint = "endpoint.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
        String clientId = "testing";

        AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, "accessKey", "secretKey");

        try {
            client.connect();
        } catch (AWSIotException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

And I got this log :

```
AVERTISSEMENT: Connect request failure
MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect connection header
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect connection header
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:676)
    ... 1 more

avr. 04, 2017 11:00:55 PM 
com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection onConnectionFailure
INFOS: Connection temporarily lost
avr. 04, 2017 11:00:55 PM 
com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient onConnectionFailure
INFOS: Client connection lost: leet
avr. 04, 2017 11:00:58 PM 
com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection$1 run
INFOS: Connection is being retried
```

At this stage I have no clue what is wrong. I was using this code for month. Nothing have changed and now it stopped working.

if somebody can help me sort this out, it would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: This happens also when you are missing your session token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/issues/23

Might be due to org.eclipse.paho getting upgrade v1.1.1

Comment: Thanks this solve my issue. I added this line to my dependencies ```"compile (group: 'org.eclipse.paho', name: 'org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3', version: '1.1.0'){force = true}"```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue, Actually, if you are using the same access key and secret key in multiple regions you will face this issue. I have created different users for each region. it fixes the issue.